# Using regex in Python to insert a space between a date and time

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of dates and times in the following format:
25/07/201711:00:00
I just want to insert whitespace between the date and time so it looks like:
25/07/2017 11:00:00

The string replace method works well but is not very robust i.e. mystring.replace("2017","2017 " ) works but only for 2017 dates. Regex sub method seems to be what I need to use but have not been successful so far. Any suggestions would be very helpful as my regex knowledge is limited.

This is closest from what I have tried:

```
>>>re.sub(r'20[0-9][0-9]', r'20[0-9][0-9] ', s)
'20[0-9][0-9] 04:00'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your dates are in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, why can't you just index your string?

```
>>> mystring[:10] + ' ' + mystring[10:]
'25/07/2017 11:00:00'
```

Comment: Great idea, wish i thought of that!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\d{4})(?=\d{2}:)
```

This needs to be replaced by a whitespace, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bJ5WU6/1/).

---

In `Python` this would be

```
import re

date = "25/07/201711:00:00"
date = re.sub(r'(?<=\d{4})(?=\d{2}:)', ' ', date)
print(date)
# 25/07/2017 11:00:00
```

As seen in the comments section, if the date is always of the same format, one might better slice the strings.

Comment: Too complicated for this case, since the strings are of equal length.

Comment: Forgive me for being pernickety, but unless the OP responds saying that the dates are _not_ always formatted the same way, I don't think we should be suggestion complicated regular expressions when a few slices will do.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: You are right that slicing will be the more efficient and straighter approach in this case. I'll however leave the answer for e.g. not well formatted dates.

Comment: Removed downvote. I'd welcome a clarifying edit, but that's obviously not my call (also, see the comments on @Alexander's answer).

Comment: *should be __suggesting__

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression for this, assuming that the dates are padded, so that they're all the same length (which seems to be the case).

```
>>> date = '25/07/201711:00:00'
>>> n    = len('dd/mm/yyyy') # Splitting index (easier to understand than a magic constant)
>>> print(date[:n] + ' ' + date[n:])
25/07/2017 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to match the full date and time in two groups, for instance like this:

```
import re
regex = r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"
re.sub(regex, r"\1 \2", "25/07/201711:00:00")
# -> '25/07/2017 11:00:00'
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too harsh (the OP mentions re:s in the title), but this is much more complicated and inefficient than it needs to be, assuming the strings are formatted the same way.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Yes, certainly. But we don't have the whole story and RegEx can be the right solution.

Comment: Too late to change the vote unless you edit. I'll hold out for the OPs response, then.